# How to read serie names from data table for the legend

Tags: highcharts

I have names for each series in dynamic table. How can I read those for the legend? When set it on with enabled flag, only one text "Serie1" is shown.
And I want it to show "Car 1, Car2, Car3 ....."?
I can see the serie name (bar name) when hovering it with mouse, but can't get the same text into legend.

```
$(function () {
var series = [{name: 'Car 1',data: [[1, 3],[4, 6],[7, 9]]},
              {name: 'Car 2',data: [[2, 3],[8, 10],[12, 18]]}, 
              {name: 'Car 3',data: [[5, 9],[1, 2]]}];

var data = [];
for(var i=0;i<series.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<series[i].data.length;j++) {
         data.push({
             x: i, 
             low: series[i].data[j][0],
             high: series[i].data[j][1],
             name: series[i].name
         });
    }
}

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        columnrange: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{data: data}]
});
});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it in working fiddle?

Comment: What do you mean, reproduce? Haven't used fiddle yet, just looked examples from it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create three series, now you set only one series. Also, you need to disable grouping and specify x property for each point, so the points from the same series are in the same row.

```
var series = [{
  name: 'Car 1',
  data: [
    [0, 1, 3],
    [0, 4, 6],
    [0, 7, 9]
  ]
}, {
  name: 'Car 2',
    data: [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [1, 8, 10],
      [1, 12, 18]
  ]
}, {
  name: 'Car 3',
  data: [
    [2, 5, 9],
    [2, 1, 2]
  ]
}];
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/kbcdkmok/1/

Comment: Still cant get this work. I have to series/row. 1st includes cars 1 and 2 data (names) and 2nd cars 1-3 (etc. dynamic data) And I need the legend to show all three cars names, not the serie's "general name". How can I do that?

Comment: Legend shows series names, not points names (unless you use a pie chart). Now,  it is not clear for me how you want to represent the data - but from what I imagine you need to reorganise the data between/inside series.

Comment: In y-axxis I have dates, in x-axxis day hours. And bar's represent items that are reserved and reservations times. I tried/wanted legend to show the represented items, so I could sort the table from it. 0-n items can be reserved each day.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

Your variable series is already defined with series name and data. use that directly [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ryfajjh1/4/)

You need to add formatter function, as per below code:

```
 tooltip: {        
    formatter:function(){

        return ''+this.point.name+':'+ this.point.low +' - '+ this.point.high ;
    }
}
```

Here is [your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ryfajjh1/1/)

Comment: It still shows only the "Serie 1", bottom of the chart. I needed it to show "Car1, car2, car3...."

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry . Your code is wrong. you need to add  series: series instead series :[{data.....}] updated fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ryfajjh1/4/

Comment: Yes, that started to look like, what Im looking for. How about, if third "car" has no name or its empty, and I wanted to removed from the the bottom?? Say those bars are shown, but only "Car1, Car2" in the bottom?

Comment: But If Im using that series: series, not series: [{ data: data}], Im loosing the data grouping. Cause Im to show the Car1 data, on its own row and Car2 to its onw.

Comment: you can use grouping: false or true in plotOption.

Comment: grouping wont do. It show all the cars in the same row. I need a car data / row.